# Verbs tense agreement in the sentence

Tags: verbs

> I **have not used** the machine regularly for a while now so I can't verify its status enough. But I **have checked** today and **cannot** reproduce the issue anymore.

Is the verb tense agreement above correct, or should it be **have checked** and **could not** instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence.

> But I have **checked today** and **cannot** reproduce the issue any more.

is okay. Personally, I would not say

> But I have checked today and could not reproduce the issue any more.

because "could not" is telic and so doesn't sit well with the adverbial "any more". So here's an alternative:

> But I have checked today and could not reproduce the issue.

meaning, at the moment that you checked you could not reproduce the issue. It's unsaid whether the issue has returned since.